LWE-based KEM using a general finite field instead of prime modulus
The learning-with-errors problem states that given matrix A and vector p = s*A + e, it's difficult to find s, if elements of A, p and s are integers modulo a prime.
I was wondering if the problem extends to a general finite field, like GF(2^32). Members of a power-of two finite field can be perfectly represented by 32 bits, so the matrix elements can be generated as uniformly random bit strings (while picking uniformly random numbers modulo a prime is annoying).
I have tried Gaussian elimination with tiny errors in GF(2^32) and it seems to be going completely wrong.
[EDIT:to Poncho's comment: The "smallness" of errors in LWE means they do not make the public vector completely wrong, so for this special case, small could be defined as "having many bits hard-set to 0" (so that much information about the non-noisy vector will remain in the noisy one). My test was flipping one bit.END EDIT].
One major implication of power-of-two field is that addition is carryless. That means that when matrix rows (and the corresponding vector members) are added together, errors in lower bits do not add up and affect the higher bits. This means we can easily XOR more than one bit of plaintext to one added row, decreasing KEM ciphertext size. Moreover, these noisy lower bits are not needed in encryption or decryption, so we may drop them to create shorter public keys. Given how wrong it was all going from changing just the last bit, I think keeping 16 bits out of 32 would be secure enough.
One not so nice consequence of carryless addition is that given a ciphertext, an attacker may learn which rows were used by constructing a set of linear equations in GF(2) with bits of matrix as coefficients and bits of the row sum as absolute terms. To prevent that, the matrix must have more rows than there are bits in one row, so public keys would be large.
So my questions are: Is such a scheme secure? If so, why is it not used in practice? If not, how can it be attacked?

Part of it might be the question "how do you define a small element in $GF(2^k)$".

Have you seen the Learning Parity with Noise problem (and its "ring" variant)? What you are describing sounds closer to this than to LWE-based KEMs. Specific KEMs you might want to look at are things like BIKE and HQC.
